# How to perform upsert in Salesforce Bulk API

Tags: api, bulk-api

I have created a class with which I can `insert`, `update` and `delete` records from Salesforce using their bulk API.  I have searched the web and have come across various resources; but I cannot seem to understand how to perform an `upsert`.

For instance, I can perform an update with the following via HTTP POST to the API:

**XML:**

```
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <operation>update</operation>
  <object>contact</object>
  <contentType>CSV</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

**CSV:**

```
Id,FirstName,LastName,Department,Birthdate,Description
"003i000000EpehQ","Tomas","Jones","Marketing","1940-06-07Z","Self-described as "
"the top"" branding guru on the West Coast"
"003i000000EpYI7","Ian","Dury","R&D","","World-renowned expert in fuzzy logic de
sign. Influential in technology purchases."
```

However, there is no such example in their documentation for an `upsert`.  How can I perform an `upsert` with my sample data?

Ref. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/api_asynch.pdf

## Update

The following code is generated when I try to do an upsert:

```
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <operation>upsert</operation>
  <object>contact</object>
  <contentType>CSV</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

When submitting the job, I get **The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

Everything works perfectly when I try to `update`, but when I try to `upsert` I get the error.  The job never gets created so the batch never even has a chance to get `upsert`'d.

Comment: Wouldn't you just change the operation to upsert and specify the external ID?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how to add an external ID.  I don't have any external IDs I just have the standard IDs that come with the "contact" object.  Not really sure what an external ID is.

Comment: @MikeChale Well, this was helpful http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/faq_import_general_what_is_an_external.htm however, I still wonder:  I don't have any external IDs for the Contacts object; so how can I tell SalesForce to `upsert`?

Comment: You need to configure an external ID field for upserting. It's a custom field on your object that is marked as external ID and it's what SF keys off of for upserting. Otherwise you're just doing an update followed by an insert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From our comment thread on the OP:

1. You need to configure an external Id field on your object; this will generally by the primary key used by your external system with which you are syncing. See http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/faq_import_general_what_is_an_external.htm and http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/custom_field_attributes.htm
2. Change your operation to `upsert` and ensure the external Id is provided in your data file.
3. **Edit** Add the external Id to your XML (see Update 2 below)

**Update 1**

I don't think there are any changes to the HTTP POST request. Sample updated CSV as requested (some values shortened for improved formatting):

```
Id,FirstName,LastName,Department,Birthdate,Description, My_External_Id__c
"003i000000EpehQ","Tomas","Jones","MKG","1940-06-07Z","Awesome", "ExternalPrimaryKey1"
"003i000000EpYI7","Ian","Dury","R&D","","Expert", "ExternalPrimaryKey2"
```

**Update 2**

I found the XML definition needed to start the job [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/NET-Development/bulk-upsert-fails-with-quot-Unable-to-parse-Job-quot/m-p/176698#M8076). Using cURL with the job.txt [example provided by Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/api_asynch.pdf), your XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
<operation>upsert</operation>
<object>Contact</object>
<externalIdFieldName>My_External_Id__c</externalIdFieldName>
<contentType>CSV</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

Note that capitalization and the order of the elements is important; if you put `<externalIdFieldName>` after `<contentType>` you will get a HTTP 400 error message stating it was unable to parse the job. After successfully submitting the job you will get an XML response with the job id, operation, object, etc... (see page 6 in the previously linked PDF.)

Comment: Mike, thanks for your answer.  Could please you provide an example of what the CSV should look like?  I understand the XML (jobInfo) should just change to `upsert` but how should the CSV change and are there any other changes I need to make such as adding additional headers to my HTTP POST request?

Comment: Added CSV example.

Comment: I have tried it and I've updated my question.  It seems I can't create the job.  I get a 400 error when trying to create a new `upsert` job.  I can create other jobs `insert`, `update` and `delete` without issue.

Comment: It looks like we need to specify the External ID in the XML when we start the job; I'm trying to figure out the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  I was wondering if you were going to try this on your own.  I am looking forward to what you have to say since I have tried other things and they have been not had success so far.

Comment: Mike, were you ever able to get the upsert working?  I have not been able to perform an upsert yet, myself.

Comment: Yes, using the syntax in my answer; see Update 2.

Comment: This handles the "(400) Bad Request" error, but I get an error in my Bulk Load Job Details screen that says, "Got an unexpected error while processing BULK-API. Contact support with error ID: 1070223644-7484 (-43640737)"  I will post a new question for this

Comment: I got it working!  I couldn't have done it without you, buddy!  Thanks.  I posted my full code at the following address so hopefully it will help someone else, too: [c# salesforce bulk api example class](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/15803/3421)

Comment: Note that order matters in the XML you send to Salesforce - sending fields out of order can make their API reject your request despite correct names.

Comment: The following helped me understand why the External ID has to be specified for the upsert to complete https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to use the Bulk API using C# so I started the [Salesforce Bulk API Starter GitHub Project](https://github.com/lfreeland/Salesforce-Bulk-API-Starter) to allow others to do the same. The project contains a test project which demonstrates how to Query, Insert, Upsert, and Delete using the framework using CSVs.

The project can also be downloaded from Nuget using Install-Package SFBulkAPIStarter. The Nuget package doesn't contain the test project.