# Bulk Api SAlesforce in C# to insert data to salesforce from csv file

Tags: bulk-api

Hie,
In reference to the code provided here on the above link:
[Unexpected Error while trying to perform simple Upsert](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15801/unexpected-error-while-trying-to-perform-simple-upsert)

This code inserts static data to salesforce using bulk api,But i want some sample code which can insert csv file data to salesforce using bulk api.

What changes i need to do to the current code for achieving this.PLease suggest the changes.
Please help me achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Please find below code snippet.

Replace your JobID in the URL and use your instance URL.

Revert in case of any issue

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(instanceurl+"/services/async/29.0/job/" + jobID+ "/batch");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            request.ContentType = "text/csv; charset=UTF-8";
            request.Headers.Add("X-SFDC-Session", atoken);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";

            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:/yourfilename.csv");

            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writeStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }


            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        }
                }


            }
```